# hibernate lock exception in mysql

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

When I try to fetch an entity from a table and try to update the same entity it is giving an error.

My sample code :

```
public String updateProfile(Hospital hospital)
    {
        System.out.println("here");
        SessionFactory sessionFactory = new AnnotationConfiguration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
        Session session=sessionFactory.openSession();
        try{
        Transaction t=session.beginTransaction();
        HttpSession sess=ServletActionContext.getRequest().getSession(false);
        Long hospitalId=(Long)sess.getAttribute("pid");
        Hospital hos = (Hospital)session.get(Hospital.class, hospitalId); 

        hos.setAbout(hospital.getAbout());
        hos.setHospitalName(hospital.getHospitalName());
        session.update(hos); 
        session.flush();

        t.commit();
        }
        catch(HibernateException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally{
            session.close();
        }
        return "success";
    }
```

and the error which i am getting is

> org.hibernate.exception.LockTimeoutException: could not execute statement
>       at org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect$1.convert(MySQLDialect.java:447)
>       at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49)
>       at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:126)
>       at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:112)
>       at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:211)
>       at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.NonBatchingBatch.addToBatch(NonBatchingBatch.java:62)
>       at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.update(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3281)
>       at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.updateOrInsert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3183)
>       at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.update(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3525)
>       at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityUpdateAction.execute(EntityUpdateAction.java:159)
>       at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:465)
>       at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:351)
>       at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:350)
>       at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:56)
>       at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1258)

Please help. The relation in hHospital object is one to many.

Comment: Are you sure invoking update() is necessary if the object is not detached? Afaik this is only needed if your hospital object has been detached. Otherwise using flush should synchronize your changes with the database.